# SQL Server isn't allocating memory

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, windows-server-2003

I've got a Windows Server 2003 Enterpise SP2 server with SQL Server 2005 SP2 Enterprise installed.  The server has 6gb of ram installed.  The SQL Server is set with a minimum memory seting of 2048mb and a max of 4096mb.  However, currently the entire server is using 2.8gb of memory and sql server has 1.7gb.

From my understanding SQL Server should, at the very least, grow to the minimum memory level and then stay between the min and max, but it's not.  It's staying at about 1.7gb.  Could something be forcing sql server to not allocate more memory?

Comment: Which edition of SQL Server did you installed?

Comment: Would it be possible to get this migrated to Database Administrators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minimum memory only defines a level that SQL Server will not drop below again, it won't fill this up preemptively. Also note that the min/max memory levels only affect the buffer pool - memory is used for many other things in SQL Server, though the buffer pool is by far the largest consumer.

Once your SQL Server consumes 2GB+, it won't let the buffer pool drop below that 2GB minimum.

Comment: Yeah i know it doesn't do it preemptively, but there's enough work being done on the server that it should be reaching the 2gb level, it just isn't.

Comment: The only 'work' that'll increase the buffer pool memory would be for you to read in more data pages. Do a scan of some large tables and you'll see it grow upwards of 2GB. But why do you want to push the memory usage up? If you want to preemptively scan data pages into memory - that's a whole other question.

Comment: I'm not wanting to "force" it to the 2gb level, it just seems that with as busy as the box is that it should have already reached that level, but it hasn't.

Comment: You can check the Page Life Expectancy performance counter to see if there's any memory contention. Probably it will be a steadily rising value (+1 ever second) since SQL Server hasn't reached its buffer pool memory limit. As long as it's steadily rising, SQL Server has more than plenty memory :)

Comment: it's not steady.  jsut for the last minute i watched it it was at 240seconds, droped down to about 150, then droped to about 40.  it then started rising slowly.

Comment: Those are very low numbers. If it's that low you've got memory contention. Are you running on a 64-bit platform? Is your "Database Pages" counter == "Target Pages" counter? (http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Memory_-_Performance_Counters)

Comment: 32bit.  no, the database pages is a lot lower than the target pages.  probably a little more than a third.

Comment: Have you enabled PAE/AWE? If not, please see this post for more info on using 2+GB on 32-bit systems: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic722925-147-1.aspx#bm725662

Comment: Ahh, PAE is enabled on the server but AWE isn't.  i've got awe set and i'm working on scheduling a reboot